# Induced current in loop

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, classical-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

If you have a loop that is spun clockwise as a magnet is moved near it, is a current induced in that loop?

[image]

If the loop were not spun, by Faraday & Lenz's laws a current would be generated in a direction that opposes the change in magnetic flux. Since the magnetic is moving closer and flux is increasing, in order to decrease flux current would be induced in a counter-clockwise direction (right hand rule).

Now the loop is spinning in a clock-wise direction.

One way of thought is to say that the opposing direction of the induced current and spinning loop "cancel" each other leading to a net zero current. This doesn't seem physically sound, however, since the result would then depend on your reference frame.

Further, if this were true isn't this a violation of Faraday's law — because the flux "is" still changing no matter what reference frame you take and hence there must be some induced current.

Some research tells me that this might be linked to [Faraday's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox) but I didn't quite understand the setup nor the resolution of the "paradox."

Comment: Why would the flux change? Certainly not due to the rotation of the loop. It will change (trivially) due to the movement of the magnet.

Comment: @CuriousOne Yes, but if the magnetic flux changes then by faraday's law there has to be an induced current, yet the answer to this problem appears to be that there isn't.

Comment: The rotation of the loop doesn't change the magnetic flux trough the loop, so why would there be an induced current? There would, of course, be an induced voltage in a radial wire, so there is a radial electric field component in the rotating observer system, but that's not going to get a current going in a wire loop with constant radius.

Comment: @CuriousOne But in the diagram the magnet is also shown moving towards the loop.

Comment: And, just like I said, that movement will cause a trivial change of the flux which has absolutely nothing to do with the rotation of the wire loop... we are back to my first comment.

Comment: @CuriousOne Pardon, but I don't quite understand. Since the magnet *is* indeed moving closer and the magnetic flux is changing, there would seem to be an induced current, no? But the given answer to the problem is that there is no induced current.

Comment: There is no induced current due to the rotation of the loop, there is an induced current due to the movement of the magnet. See my first comment. There is no paradox here.

Comment: @CuriousOne The question asks what happens when both happen together though. If the loop is rotated *and* the magnet is brought closer, would there be an induced current?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not going to understand my first comment, no matter how many times I repeat it. I would suggest you get yourself a magnet, a piece of wire and a multimeter and you simply do the experiment.

Comment: @CuriousOne :( I got that the answer is that the flux changes and current is generated due to the motion of the manget, but the answer to the problem in the book states that there is no current generated when the magnet moves closer and the loop is spun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34783/discussion-between-curiousone-and-1110101001).